# Recursive flatten with lazy evaluation iterator

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, lazy

I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
def flatten(lst):
    flat = []
    for x in lst:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__') and not isinstance(x, basestring):
            flat.extend(flatten(x))
        else:
            flat.append(x)
    return flat


In [21]: a=[1, [2, 3, 4, [5, 6]], 7]

In [22]: flatten(a)
Out[22]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

..into a version that would flatten the iterable, but return values in a lazy manner. Now, this works:

```
def flat_fugly(s):
    if iterable(s):
        for x in s:
            yield chain.from_iterable(flat_fugly(x))
    else:
        yield takewhile(lambda x: True, [s])


list(islice(chain.from_iterable(flat_fugly(a)), 0, 6))
Out[34]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But, as the name suggests... Is there a cleaner/better way?

Not to mention that I have to apply `chain.from_iterable` to `flat_fugly` anyway while I'd prefer to have plain iterator (I could wrap it in another function that would use `chain.from_iterable` of course, but still if it could be all made to fit in one more elegant function that would be preferable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not my idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/641955), but I think this is better:

```
import collections


def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(item, basestring):
            for sublst in flatten(item):
                yield sublst
        else:
            yield item
```

Comment: In Python 3.3+ you can replace the inner `for` loop on the recursive call with `yield from flatten(item)`.

Comment: that was lazy enough ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compiler module

```
from compiler.ast import flatten

>>> flatten([1,[2,3])
>>> [1,2,3]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: look at /lib/python2.7/compiler/ast.py / flatten definition, that's plain eager evaluation flatten like one I was trying to rewrite, while I'm looking for lazy iterator (lazy ~= conserves memory)